# ignore jar packaging inside war maven tomcat plugin?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jersey, maven-tomcat-plugin, spring-jersey

I am using maven [Maven Tomcat 8 plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin?repo=alfresco-public) to start up my tomcat server locally and deploy a war file with the intellij IDE.

For some reason when I try to start it with maven tomcat 8 plugin, it shows following stack trace and not getting up.

```
n.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.AbstractInstanceResolver$1.run(AbstractInstanceResolver.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.AbstractInstanceResolver$1.run(AbstractInstanceResolver.java:78)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.AbstractInstanceResolver.invokeMethod(AbstractInstanceResolver.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.SingletonResolver.start(SingletonResolver.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.start(InstanceResolver.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But when I try to do it with a separate tomcat container (without using maven tomcat 8 plugin or support of IDE), it starts all ok.

I investigated that this happens because of a library ([spring-jersey3.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3)) that bundles inside my war file. When I remove that from war and try with maven tomcat plugin, it is all ok too. As I found this error happens because it tries to init a spring application context at the start up. But it only happens when I try to do with maven tomcat plugin.

Anyhow I ***need*** that lib for my work. I can't exclude it from war.

Does any one know any work around to get rid of this? It may be

- configure disabling init the spring application context at start up.
- configure maven tomcat 8 plugin to ignore that lib or init process.
- Or any other way to do without excluding the lib.

Comment: Can you show your pom/relevant spring/jersey version?

Comment: spring-jersey3 lib version 2.15

Comment: @user7294900   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3/2.15